# ASP.NET:Required Field Validator not working

Tags: asp.net, validation

I've got a weird problem that i don't understand why it happened.

I made a content page so a user can send me a message to my email and made a few TextBox's that are linked to some validators.

when i first made the page i hed 1 Regular Expression validator and every thing worked out fine like i planed it, But then i decided to delete the Regular Expression validator and now i got a problem with the Required Field validator.

when i press submit the page do a post back like there isn't any validators on the page.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something (I'm pretty new at asp.net)
here is the markup:

```
<!-- Regular Expression Validtor for the Name Text Box 
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="NameExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="nameTextBox"
ValidationExpression="[אבגדהוזחטיכלמנסעפצקרשתץףןם\s\.]*" Display="Dynamic">  </asp:RegularExpressionValidator> -->

<!--The Name Text Box -->  
<asp:TextBox ID="nameTextBox" class="TextBoxes" runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="True"  ValidationGroup="g" ></asp:TextBox> <span class="infoText">:שם</span>

<!-- Required Field Validator for the Name Text Box -->
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="nameTextBox" 
Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="g"   ErrorMessage="please enter your name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<br />
<br />

<!-- Phone Text Box -->
<asp:TextBox ID="phoneTestBox" class="TextBoxes" runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="True" ValidationGroup="g"  ></asp:TextBox> <span class="infoText">:טלפון</span>

<!-- Requierd Field Validator Phone Text Box -->
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="phoneTestBox" 
Display="Dynamic"  ValidationGroup="g" ErrorMessage="please enter your phone"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<br />
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="messagTextBox" runat="server"  class="TextBoxes" TextMode="MultiLine"
Text="asdasdadasdasdasd"></asp:TextBox> <span class="infoText">:הודעה</span> 

<asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" Text="send message"  ValidationGroup="g" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use [HTML comments](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp) to comment out server side controls but `<%-- --%>`:

```
<%-- 
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="NameExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="nameTextBox"
ValidationExpression="[אבגדהוזחטיכלמנסעפצקרשתץףןם\s\.]*" Display="Dynamic">  </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
--%>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4acf8afk.aspx

Comment: that fixed that and i learnd somthing new thank you :) didnt know asp.net hed diffrent comment

Comment: Fyi, if using Visual Studio, use the key command (Ctrl-K, C) to comment and (Ctrl-K, U) to un-comment. That should pick an appropriate comment style.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any specific use of **AutoPostBack="True"** in textbox? if not then just remove it from all textboxes, also you need to give **ValidationGroup="g"** for only validator controls, there is no need to give it in textbox controls.

Comment: Both suggestions do not help in this case and they are not advisable per se. `AutoPostBack` lets a postback occur as soon as the user leaves the textbox or presses `Enter`. So if this is desired use it. [`ValidationGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) on controls others than validators could also be helpful to clarify relationships(even if the validators would be removed later).

Answer (score 0):

first of all, ensure the validation group of the validation summary matches?
If that's correct try using validation method:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Validate();
}
```